# Remove taxonomy widget from "PAGE" post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pages, widgets, taxonomy, metabox

For internal purpose I created taxonomy named "CLIENT" for the "PAGES" post .

It's generated a widget in pages (picture below).

I use ACF to manages my client categories (I create a specific field) so i want to remove or hide this widget for all my users role by adding code to my function.php

any idea?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: _so i want to remove or hide this widget for all my users role_ Do you mean you wish to remove this box from the edit page screen for **all** users, or for any user other than the admin?

Comment: From the edit page screen for all users

Answer (score 1):

In your [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) args, set `meta_box_cb => false`

> 'meta_box_cb'
>   (bool|callable) Provide a callback function for the meta box display. If not set, post_categories_meta_box() is used for hierarchical taxonomies, and post_tags_meta_box() is used for non-hierarchical. **If false, no meta box is shown.**

```
$args = array(
               //other args 
               'meta_box_cb' => false,
                );

register_taxonomy( $args );
```